# powershell - launching local apps fast

Tags: powershell, invoke, asynchronous

I am building a kiosk type config script on low-spec hardware.

At the end of the script, it runs the various apps for the user to interact with. I currently use a plain Invoke-Command "`path\to\app.exe`". I want to get the interface up and running as quickly as possible. I want to launch the apps asynchronous.

I know there  is start-job, and the `-asJob` flag in `Invoke-Command`, but they don't seem to work with launching visual apps. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows subsystem (visual) EXEs start asynchronously by default.  And you don't need Invoke-Command to invoke an exe.  If you exeute notepad.exe like so:

```
PS> Notepad
PS>
```

Note that the PowerShell prompt returns immediately while notepad is still running.  The same applies in a script.

Comment: ahhhh, thanks. I guess this hardware was so low-spec it seemed they weren't async.